# __attribute__ optimize, specifying multiple flags, and failing code at different -O levels

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, attributes, eabi

I have some code that is being compiled with GCC for a micro.  I noticed that when compiling the debug build, the system works just fine.  But when I compile the release build, the system does not boot up.

After working on the issue for awhile, I narrowed down the problem to one function where if I specify a lesser optimization level (-O0 instead of -Os), the system will boot up just fine in the release build.  So there is presumably a flag that -Os sets that is causing the code in that particular function to not work.

I had planned to track down the underlying issue by taking all the flags that -Os sets, and finding the one that causes the system not to boot.

I was trying to do the following:

```
__attribute__ ((optimize("-fauto-inc-dec", "-fcompare-elim", "-fcprop-registers", "-fdce", "-fdefer-pop", "-fdelayed-branch", "-fdse", "-fguess-branch-probability", "-fif-conversion2", "-fif-conversion", "-fipa-pure-const", "-fipa-profile", "-fipa-reference", "-fmerge-constants", "-fsplit-wide-types", "-ftree-bit-ccp", "-ftree-builtin-call-dce", "-ftree-ccp", "-ftree-ch", "-ftree-copyrename", "-ftree-dce", "-ftree-dominator-opts", "-ftree-dse", "-ftree-forwprop", "-ftree-fre", "-ftree-phiprop", "-ftree-sra", "-ftree-pta", "-ftree-ter", "-funit-at-a-time")))
```

and then eliminate flags until the system would boot.  The problem is, is that I kept narrowing it down and narrowing it down, until I discovered that I can't get even set a single flag and get the system to boot.

So now I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong with the way that I'm setting the optimization.  If I put in a superfluous non-existent flag somewhere in the middle of those flags, like -fiam-fake-flag, the compiler detects it and spits out an error (which at first made me feel like I was setting these flags correctly).

I don't want to use pragma, because:

" Each function that is defined after this point is as if attribute((optimize("STRING"))) was specified for that function. "

and I only want the optimization on this one function so I can narrow down the problem.

So, am I setting these flags incorrectly?  Is there a better way to specify a whole bunch of compiler flags for only 1 specific function?

If it weren't going on a micro, I could just specify all the flags I want in the Makefile and apply it to all functions, but doing so makes the program too big to fit on the micro.

Comment: 99.9% of 'code works/doesn't' with -0X set' are UB-style bugs.

Comment: @MartinJames: For a standard platform, I'd agree (100%) with that statistic.  However, if the OP is working on some wacky microcontroller with an immature toolchain, there's a >0.1% chance that there's a compiler bug, in my experience...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I get it all the time on ARM uC.  It's always been UB-ish, ie. my crappy code :(

Comment: I know what code is breaking the system's ability to boot, but was hoping to understand the reason.  I am building upon FreeRTOS.  The problematic code is a forced delay between SPI messages.  In a module that has its own thread, I start a timer and unset a flag.  A message cannot be sent until the flag is reset.  Upon timer expiry, the flag is reset.  The timer, a FreeRTOS module, is supposed to be thread safe, but the timer gets stuck when it tries to set the flag.  If the messages can't be sent, the system won't boot.

Comment: But the question is, is why do different optimization levels affect the timer's ability to expire and set a flag correctly?

Comment: You have your OS in the boot code?

Comment: I guess what I put is a bit misleading.  The system won't "go live".  Many things have to occur for the system to "go live", including sending and receiving messages with the peripherals.  It's during this sending/receiving step where things go awry, and prevent the system from "going live", leaving it in an unusable state from the get-go.

Comment: Is your flag declared as `volatile`? Try posting the problematic function.

Comment: that is TOTALLY what it was.  Thank you, egur.  I'm fairly new to programming for hardware, so I didn't have a very strong grasp of volatility.

Comment: also, can I not upvote your answer since it was a comment?  I'm new to stack overflow too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your flag declared as `volatile`? Try posting the problematic function. – egur

that is TOTALLY what it was. Thank you, egur. – Mike Gibson